# Tableview cell separating line disappears when tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with custom tableview cells with the separator line between each cell.  I recently began implementing multi cell selection when in editing mode.  In order to have the blue circled checkmarks when each cell is selected, I changed cell `selectionStyle` from `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone` to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault`.  To get rid of the gray shade when the cell is selected I just implemented a white background like this:

```
UIView * cellBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
cellBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.multipleSelectionBackgroundView = cellBackgroundView;
cell.selectedBackgroundView = cellBackgroundView;
```

The problem is that when I'm not in edit mode, the separator line disappears whenever the cell is selected, but when I select a cell in edit mode, the line remains. Any idea how to resolve this so the separator always remains?

Comment: The possible reason here is whenever you edit cell the view `cellBackgroundView` will overlap separator lines. Check with removing it.

Comment: Thats what I thought initially.  I tested it by reducing `cellBackgroundView.frame.size.height` by quite a bit and it was still occurring.  Also, that wouldn't explain why its only happening when I select a cell when I'm not in edit mode.  The lines remain when I select a cell while in edit mode.

Comment: It could be possible that its bug from Xcode. Check with different simulation (change device version) also check with different Xcode version.

Answer (score 0):

try following:

Add this lines

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

at the begining of didSelectRowAtIndexPath

this is weird bug which exists since iOS7.0

Answer (score 0):

I know that the cell separator disappearing is a common issue, but none of the current solutions seemed to solve my problem so I came to the conclusion that I would need to toggle my selectionStyle to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone` when my `tableView` is not in editing mode and `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue`when I'm in editing mode.  I was able to achieve this by calling the following in my view controller containing my table view:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(tableView.editing)
    {
        [((customTableViewCellClass*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]) changeSelectionStyle:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        [((customTableViewCellClass*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]) changeSelectionStyle:NO];
    }

return indexPath;
}
```

Then in my custom `tableviewcell` class I call the following:

```
-(void) changeSelectionStyle: (BOOL) selected
{
    if(selected)
    {
        self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
    }
    else
    {
        self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

}
```

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I left the code that changed the view for `multipleSelectionBackgroundView`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIView * cellBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
    cellBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.multipleSelectionBackgroundView = cellBackgroundView;
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = cellBackgroundView;
}
```